# How to create old looking/ cracked glass

Tags: modeling, texturing, eevee-render-engine, windows, glass

I am looking for old looking cracked glass for a window in a shack scene.
I have looked everywhere but can find a tutorial or material or model on this

please can someone help me on this

thanks

Comment: Try using a Voronoi texture, it looks somewhat like cracked glass and would be a great start.

Answer (score 7):

Here, try this:

[image: GlassFullGraph]

As Eric pointed out in the comments, the secret here is a Voronai texture set to "distance to edge". I used ColorRamps to remove all the grayscale and leave only black outlines. I made a large, medium, and small set of cracks and mixed them together. I then used this combo as a main image (BaseColor), as a basis for a normal map, and I also inverted it to make an alpha mask.

[image: CracksGraph]

Final result looks like this:

[image: FullProduct]

This can obviously be made better by creating more distortion among the cracks, but I feel this is a good place to start. I'll upload the .blend file so you can experiment.

File is here - [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: very nice!!!!!!